# Copy nested objects in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, copy, deep-copy

So I have the following classes:

```
class A{
    public A(int n1){
        n=n1;
    }
    int n;
}

class B extends A{
    public B(int n2){
        super(n2);
        cnt=1;
    }
    int cnt;
}
class C extends B{
    public C(int n3){
        super(n3);
        clr="red";
    }
    String clr;
}

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A a,b,c,d,e;
        a=new B(200); d=a.copy();
        b=new C(100); e=b.copy();
    }
}
```

I am asked to define the method `copy()` in classes A,B,C. The copy method essentially makes a copy of all nested objects.

I have 2 questions:

1. I don't see any nested objects being constructed, why does he ask me to make a copy of all nested objects? Is it because when I construct a subclass object, a base class object is constructed and nests inside the subclass object?
2. Is it correct to write the method as follows (take class B for example):

```
class B extends A{
    public B(int n2){
        super(n2);
        cnt=1;
    }
    int cnt;
    public A copy(){
        A copy_ref=new B(1);
        ((B)copy_ref).cnt=this.cnt;
        copy_ref.n=super.n;
        return copy_ref;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing to different concepts.

You are confusing the [has-a relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a) with the [is-a relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a).

In your code C is a B and also an A: C has an is-a relationship with B and A. 
C does not contain an instance of B or A (that would be an has-a relationship).

Since C is an B and A, it contains all the members of B and A. Calling a copy of C will copy all of its members variables. You do not need to create any particular method, you can just use the [already defined Object.clone method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).

If you want to define your own clone/copy method I suggest you look at [the following article on the subject](http://www.xenoveritas.org/blog/xeno/java_copy_constructors_and_clone).

Enjoy !

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually understand the relationship expressed by inheritance and composition. I just got confused by "nested objects". Where the heck are the nested objects in this case??? And the copy() method actually works. I just wanna make sure that's what the question asks for.